# Create dynamic json response based on string c#

Tags: c#, json, backend

I am facing problem to create this json response from back-end:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "code":200,
   "data":[
      {
         "employeeName":"Zaigham",
         "employeeAttendance":{
            "3":{
               "id":2,
               "checkInTime":"2021-03-03T16:48:10.1181856",
               "lateDuration":10,
               "employeeName":"Zaigham",
               "employeeDeviceID":2,
               "qrCodeId":"QRCodeID",
               "dayOfAttendance":3,
               "attendanceStatus":0
            },
            "15":{
               "id":8,
               "checkInTime":"2021-03-02T16:48:10.1181856",
               "lateDuration":10,
               "employeeName":"Zaigham",
               "employeeDeviceID":2,
               "qrCodeId":"QRCodeID",
               "dayOfAttendance":15,
               "attendanceStatus":0
            },
            "1":{
               "id":11,
               "checkInTime":"2021-03-01T16:48:10.1181856",
               "lateDuration":0,
               "employeeName":"Zaigham",
               "employeeDeviceID":2,
               "qrCodeId":"QRCodeID",
               "dayOfAttendance":1,
               "attendanceStatus":0
            },
            "4":{
               "id":2,
               "checkInTime":"2021-03-05T16:48:10.1181856",
               "lateDuration":10,
               "employeeName":"Zaigham",
               "employeeDeviceID":2,
               "qrCodeId":"QRCodeID",
               "dayOfAttendance":4,
               "attendanceStatus":0
            }
         }
      },
      
      }
   ]
}
```

in **employeeAttendance** object we have different objects which will be created on behalf of **dayOfAttendance number**. so every object should be created on dayofAttendance basis and dayOfAttendance will be not be repetitive.

> I have also applied dictionary but i was'nt able to convert it in json
> format

Here is my class struct.

```
namespace abc
{
   public class AttendancModel
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public EmployeeAttendance EmployeeAttendance { get; set; }                                
    }
    public class EmployeeAttendance
    {
        #region Properties
        public Dictionary<int,Att> KeyValuePairsAttendance { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
    public class Att {
        public DateTime CheckInTime { get; set; }
        public int LateDuration { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeDeviceID { get; set; }
        public int DayOfAttendance { get; set; }
        public AttendanceStatus AttendanceStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

can someone help regarding this

Comment: Can you share the class structure you are using?

Comment: So, you get some data from a query and the `employeeAttendance` object represent Records from the db (so, you need to generate the JSON, not deserialize it - is it so?). Now, you have to to pivot the objects using the value of one of the Fields. Do you have to, i.e., is it mandatory? Should the data be represented unordered, as you're showing here, or the indexer should order it? -- Can you post the code that tries to convert to Dictionary the `employeeAttendance` array?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya sure i am updating question

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Unit Test for the situation you describe:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JsonResponse
{
    public class AttendancModel
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public EmployeeAttendance EmployeeAttendance { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmployeeAttendance
    {
        #region Properties
        public Dictionary<int, Att> KeyValuePairsAttendance { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
    public class Att
    {
        public DateTime CheckInTime { get; set; }
        public int LateDuration { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public long EmployeeDeviceID { get; set; }
        public int DayOfAttendance { get; set; }
        public int AttendanceStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tests
    {

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var model = new AttendancModel
            {
                EmployeeName = "Zaigham",
                EmployeeAttendance = new EmployeeAttendance
                {
                    KeyValuePairsAttendance = CreateAttendees()
                }
            };

            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

            Assert.False(string.IsNullOrEmpty(json));
        }

        private static Dictionary<int, Att> CreateAttendees()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, Att>();

            {
                var att = new Att
                {
                    CheckInTime = DateTime.Now,
                    LateDuration = 10,
                    EmployeeName = "Zaigham",
                    EmployeeDeviceID = 2,
                    DayOfAttendance = 3, // <-- ONLY DIFFERENCE!
                    AttendanceStatus = 0
                };

                dict.Add(att.DayOfAttendance, att);
            }

            {
                var att = new Att
                {
                    CheckInTime = DateTime.Now,
                    LateDuration = 10,
                    EmployeeName = "Zaigham",
                    EmployeeDeviceID = 2,
                    DayOfAttendance = 15, // <-- ONLY DIFFERENCE!
                    AttendanceStatus = 0
                };

                dict.Add(att.DayOfAttendance, att);
            }

            {
                var att = new Att
                {
                    CheckInTime = DateTime.Now,
                    LateDuration = 10,
                    EmployeeName = "Zaigham",
                    EmployeeDeviceID = 2,
                    DayOfAttendance = 1, // <-- ONLY DIFFERENCE!
                    AttendanceStatus = 0
                };

                dict.Add(att.DayOfAttendance, att);
            }

            {
                var att = new Att
                {
                    CheckInTime = DateTime.Now,
                    LateDuration = 10,
                    EmployeeName = "Zaigham",
                    EmployeeDeviceID = 2,
                    DayOfAttendance = 4, // <-- ONLY DIFFERENCE!
                    AttendanceStatus = 0
                };

                dict.Add(att.DayOfAttendance, att);
            }

            return dict;
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like the expected, doesn't it? (see attachment)
[image]

Comment: Thanks but the issue i got this sort of JSON
"[{\"EmployeeName\":\"Zaigham\",\"EmployeeAttendance\":{\"KeyValuePairsAttendance\":{\"3\":{\"CheckInTime\":\"2021-03-03T16:48:10.1181856\",\"LateDuration\":408,\"EmployeeName\":\"Zaigham\",\"EmployeeDeviceID\":2,\"DayOfAttendance\":3,\"AttendanceStatus\":0}}]"

Comment: Even i made Formatting.None and one more thing i got KeyValuePairsAttendance parameter too which i don't need